# How to make checkbox checked if condition is true?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On page load i am checking if attestationStatus flag is approved i want to make check box checked , with below implementation its not working, Any idea what implemented wrong.

main.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" 
            ng-model="aprv" 
            name="attestorFlag" 
            id="attestorFlag" 
            ng-value="'Y'"> I attest 
        </label>
</div>
```

main.js

```
if ($scope.attestorObj.attestationStatus === 'approved') {
    $scope.aprv = 'Y';
}
```

Comment: Maybe remove one of the equal signs in your if statement? Unless your checking identity as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `ng-value`. Use only `ng-model` and set the `$scope.aprv` value to `true` or `false`.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="aprv" name="attestorFlag" id="attestorFlag">
```

Controller:

```
if ($scope.attestorObj.attestationStatus === 'approved') {
    $scope.aprv = true;
}
```

http://codepen.io/ces/pen/gpexBX

Answer (score 1):

you could add the condition to your checkbox itself by adding the ng-checked.
think this should work for you, hope this helps or gets you in the right direction

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" 
                    ng-checked="$scope.attestorObj.attestationStatus == 'approved'"
                    ng-model="aprv"
                    name="attestorFlag" id="attestorFlag"> I attest </label>
        </div>
```